# Free space size information

Tags: c++

I wanted to know, how can i find the free space available in a drive in windows using C++. I have a path of the directory as input and I wanted to know if this drive or this directory has enough space to save my data. Main constraint is I should use only C++, not the VC++ or any kind of other windows programing because this application has to interact in batch mode to other applications.

Comment: First, Visual Studio (VC++) can create normal, unmanaged, console only C++ applications, even the Express version. Second, http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: GetDiskFreeSpaceEx  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense why can you not use VC++, surely the easiest thing is to call a WinAPI method to get the disk space http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364935%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, otherwise you will need to find another library to query this information from the OS which is more than likely calling this winapi anyway?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to know free space available on Windows you can read this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364937(v=vs.85).aspx

On POSIX systems, you can try this:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/sys/statvfs.h.html

I believe that get the free space available without using the file system is not possible, because you will need to identify when a sequence of bytes is a file... (You will need to identify the total number of blocks on your HDD, which blocks are reserved for the system, a flag for the blocks that are in use and a flag for the ones that are free and probably a lot more related stuff...)

I can be wrong, but this is my guess...

I hope you understand...

=)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

A portable solution is to use Boost.Filesystem [space](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#space) which returns a `space_info` struct with the relevant information.